# MP3 Content Type for Creating a MediaSource

Tags: c#, media-player

Using MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, content type), what is the content type for a "audio-16khz-64kbitrate-mono-mp3" stream? I have tried numerous values which result in the mediasource not being created.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you don't tag the language, how do you expect people to see your question? You just wasted your bounty.

Comment: The tag was present, C#. Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Nope, you created the question with these 2 tags: "media-player" and "media-source" (the last one being incorrect because it refers to a JavaScript API). Yesterday someone added the Java tag (by mistake). Since I'm watching the Java tag, I noticed your question. Then I realized it was about C# and not Java, so I fixed the tags. Just look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63566895/revisions) if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be one of these

- `audio/mpeg`
- `audio/x-mpeg`
- `audio/mp3`
- `audio/x-mp3`

Comment: Those parameters don't work. See additions to original comment above. The last image is to show that there is content to the stream being used.

Answer (score 0):

The current 'contentType' parameter value needed for MediaSource.CreateFromStream for the provided stream is not one of  the 'audio/xxx' type specifications (it has been "audio/wav" for years in my code), but "{Name = "MemoryStream" FullName = "System.IO.MemoryStream"}" [with enclosing curly brackets]. This is the value is returned by "stream.GetType()"

It is also important to know that the stream received, when assigned to a variable, has its property ".position" set to the length of the stream and needs to be reset to zero to be read.